# MySQL insert new value when no other like that

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sql-update, sql-insert

I am trying to solve the problem with insert new value into table. Primary key is ID not email... Before insert i need check other records for email value. If no one match inserted email, data is inserted. But i canot write correct code for that...

```
IF EXIST (SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = "email")  
THEN 
    BEGIN 
        'We Have Records of this Customer' 
    END                                          
ELSE 
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO users 
        VALUES (null,'email9','password9','forename9','lastname9')
    END
END IF
```

Or:

```
IF SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE email = 'email' > 0
THEN 
    BEGIN
    //email exist
    END
ELSE 
    BEGIN
    //inserting
    END
END IF
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a good use case for MySQL `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax.

First of all, you want to create a `UNIQUE` constraint on column `email`. This is the proper way to represent your business rule:

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD CONSTRAINT users_unique_email UNIQUE (email);
```

Now, if the record that is about to be inserted would generate a duplicate on the primary key or on that `UNIQUE` constraint, then MySQL lets you turn the operation to an `UPDATE` instead.

In your case, since you want not to update anything in that case, you can simply re-assign the `email` column (which we know is the same here).

Consider:

```
INSERT INTO users 
    VALUES (null,'email9','password9','forename9','lastname9')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET email = 'mail9';
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment, but I post this. I recommend making an external script like in python or java to do this for you by selecting * and parsing through the output because SQL itself does not have the power to do this.